# what is the ruamel.yaml alternative to pyyaml's loader=FullLoader

Tags: python, pyyaml, ruamel.yaml

I have to covert a project from pyyaml to ruamel.yaml. One function is using pyyaml.FullLoader and i cannot find a ruamel.yaml alternative to this loader.

I do not know exactly why FullLoader was initially chosen but it is a loading trusted files only.

is it `ruamel.YAML(typ="unsafe")`?

If not, how do these two yaml loading methods differ?

edit* The file this function loads can contain unix environment variables such as $PROJ_PATH incase that makes a difference.

Comment: Do you have an example of an actual tag used? Probably something like `!!python/object`, or are there any calls to `add_constructor` in the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not completely familiar with the `FullLoader`, it was added after `ruamel.yaml` was forked from PyYAML 3.14. But it is probably what used to be the default (unsafe) loader from PyYAML and you would replace that with:

```
from pathlib import Path
import ruamel.yaml

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML(typ='unsafe', pure=True)

data = yaml.load(Path('/some/path/to/a/file.yaml'))
```

The primary difference (apart from bugfixes) is that `ruamel.yaml` used in this way supports YAML 1.2 (the default) and YAML 1.1, and PyYAML only a subset of YAML 1.1. So if you rely on YAML 1.1 specifics ( e.g. Yes being a boolean and 12:34:56 being a sexagesimal ) you should also specify:

```
yaml.version((1, 1))
```

if the files don't have a `%YAML 1.1` directive.

If you leave out `pure=True` you'll also will be using a C based scanner that tokenizes the data, which is quite a
bit faster, but also currently not fully YAML 1.2 compatible.
There are valid YAML constructs that `ruamel.yaml` supports but `PyYAML` doesn't, but if your document currently works with PyYAML, you are unlikely to use these :-)

The main difference between using the "unsafe" loader and the (default) round-trip loader is  how tags that start with `!!python/object` are loaded. The unsafe loader executes the code specified with that tag (usually creating a Python object or calling a Python function during loading, and that is what makes this unsafe). The round-trip mode can handle YAML documents with these tags as well. But it will safely create a normal `ruamel.yaml` object and put the tag on an attribute for further inspection (and dumping), **without executing any code specified in the tag**. This makes the round-trip loader safe but also able to deal with tags in YAML without necessarily having objects registered.

The object created most often is a `CommentedMap`, but `CommentedList` or a primitive can also be created with a tag attribute, depening on the node the tag in YAML applies to.

If possible to implement I recommend searching for the actual tags used, loading with the default round-trip loader, and walking over the data tree checking for tags that need evaluation, replacing data.